# Datetime ints in fewer lines

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-dynamodb

Right now I am using the following functions to calculate a date and time int like this (ymd), (hms). I believe it is easier to do this for comparison.

```
def getDayAsInt():
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    year = time.strftime("%Y")
    month=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%m"))
    day=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%d"))
    return year+month+day
def getTimeOfDay():
    day=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%d"))
    hour=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%H"))
    minute=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%M"))
    second=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%S"))
    return hour+minute+second
```

I initially tried something like this:

```
    'date': str(datetime.now()),
```

However I ran into an issue of easier generating a date range to query it. For example if today is 20140616 I can simply query dates between 20140601 and 20140616 where as generating all of the possible date times is harder. Does that make sense?

Ex I want to find out events that happened today but having a date time string stored in dynamodb is harder (more things to match to) to match.

I'm wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way? Is breaking the date and time down like that done? Should I take this:

```
    year = time.strftime("%Y")
    month=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%m"))
    day=makeTimeTwoDigit(time.strftime("%d"))
```

And do it inn one line? Like should I do time.strftime("%Y%m%d")?

Comment: "should I do time.strftime('%Y%m%d')" -- Why not give it a try?  :-)

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the comparisons in python, an easier solution would be to use builtin `datetime` objects and the normal comparison operators, like `<` and `>`.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

if datetime(2006, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0) <= dt_object < datetime(2006, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0):
    # do something when date is anytime on June 5th, 2006
```

If you must do the comparison in the query, you can use regular string comparison as long as your dates are stored in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.  The advantage of ISO-8601 is that chronological sorting is equivalent to lexographic sorting, i.e. you can treat them as normal strings.

The equivalent comparison using ISO-8601 format:

```
'2006-06-05T00:00:00Z' <= dt < '2006-06-06T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

I thinking breaking the day (year/month/date) from time (hour/minute/second) is the cleanest solution for you since you want to do query on day.